# ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Devise::Registrations#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-4.1, rails-i18n, devise-confirmable

I'm newbie in Rails and I don't know what to do with tis error, please help (with explanation):

ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Devise::Registrations#create

Showing /home/ubuntu/workspace/mamchut418/app/views/devise/mailer/confirmation_instructions.html.erb where line #5 raised:

No route matches {:action=>"create", :confirmation_token=>"24GGcednzrEXEzaR82AC", :controller=>"devise/confirmations"} missing required keys: [:locale]

Extracted source (around line #5):

```
3 | <p><%= _('You can confirm your account email through the link below:') %>p>
4 |
5 | <p><%= link_to _('Confirm my account'), confirmation_url(@resource, confirmation_token: @token) %></p>
```

app/views/devise/mailer/confirmation_instructions.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_devise_mailer_confirmation_instructions_html_erb___1326125006769773887_55918960'

Request

Parameters:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
"authenticity_token"=>"pY7ApWH/WTOVTFGifeV7QbubuNch/EzCJWjaXg7t+i5iYpI=",
"user"=>{"email"=>"qwerty@gmail.com",
"password"=>"[FILTERED]",
"password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"},
"commit"=>"Registrovať",
"locale"=>"sk"}
```

Session dump

```
_csrf_token: "pY7ApWH/WTkukoOVTFGifeV7QNch/EzCJWjaXg7t+i5iYpI="
locale: "sk"
session_id: "01f6f1f89089a5ef29326e80b0d44f79"
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an `i18n` (internationalization) issue, where it needs to know what yoru locale is.  Specify the default locale for your internationalization in your config/application.rb file

```
config.i18n.default_locale = :en
```

or perhaps you want Slovak

```
config.i18n.default_locale = :sk
```

EDIT

You can also specify the locale when you call the confirmation_url method...

```
<p><%= link_to _('Confirm my account'), confirmation_url(@resource, confirmation_token: @token, locale: 'en') %></p>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your advice, I did it, cleared cache, restarted server, but that error still remains :-(

Comment: One guy at Github recommended me to do this: - "Based on the error, it looks like you need to pass in the "locale" option on the "confirmation_url" helper, that should work." - Maybe it is the solution, but for me it is the "spanish village". I don't know how to do it. Can you explain me it please?

Comment: He's suggesting you change this line by passing the locale option... here's the revised line... `<p><%= link_to _('Confirm my account'), confirmation_url(@resource, confirmation_token: @token, locale: 'en') %></p>`

Comment: Yesss...! it works. Thnx. It probably would be necessary to replace 'en' with current locale variable to work proper in all enabled locales...